# Error:EADDRINUSE Debian 7

Tags: php, node.js, debian

So i am making a website, and when i was launching the NODE it came with this strange error. Just post if you need more information

The serverOs is Debian 7 64 bit if needed

```
[2016-06-29 23:40:15.575] [TRACE] [default] - Strange error
[2016-06-29 23:40:15.576] [DEBUG] [default] - { [Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::7549]
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 7549 }
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::7549
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:896:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1250:14)
    at listen (net.js:1286:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1382:5)
    at Server.listen.Server.attach         (/root/bot/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:216:9)
    at null._onTimeout (/root/bot/site.js:623:29)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

If you know how to fix this i would be highly thankful

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing indicates that the port your piece of code is trying to bind to has already been bound to. Check to see if a different port works or that your code isn't calling a `listen` more than once on the same port.

Comment: But how do i check if it isnt listening more then once, do i have to go through the files? Or is there a specific command